# lambda expression NoSuchMethodError (lambda in lambda)

Tags: java, android, lambda

nesting a lambda expression inside a lambda expression I get this error:

> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main Process: io.celox.brutus, PID:
>   22471 java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No direct method
>   (Ljava/lang/Object;)V in class
>   Lio/celox/brutus/activities/-$Lambda$0; or its super classes
>   (declaration of 'io.celox.brutus.activities.-$Lambda$0' appears in
>   /data/app/io.celox.brutus-MAG1aSsx-t_HT5qBjCm9lQ==/base.apk) at
>   io.celox.brutus.activities.WrapperDetailActivity.lambda$-io_celox_brutus_activities_WrapperDetailActivity_lambda$1(WrapperDetailActivity.java:87)
>   at io.celox.brutus.activities.-$Lambda$2.$m$0(Unknown Source:4) at
>   io.celox.brutus.activities.-$Lambda$2.onClick(Unknown Source:0) at
>   android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5875) at
>   android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:23500) at
>   android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751) at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6408) at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) at
>   com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:232)
>   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:751)

The witchcraft:

```
mBtnAddField.setOnClickListener(view -> {
    PopupMenu mp = new PopupMenu(WrapperDetailActivity.this, mBtnAddField);
    ...
    mp.setOnMenuItemClickListener(item -> {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        ...
```

It seems related to the build. In most cases the code works fine, but after some builds it will consistently fail. Rebuilding the project (**without** any changes in the code) "fixes" the issue... Until it's coming back.

Comment: Sounds like a bug, possibly?

Comment: Agreed, sounds like a race condition with registering the handler and checking for the handler

Comment: Have inserted a extra pair of { } maybe the compiler is optimising too much.. will update if it helped.

Comment: Rather that you are running against different class files than you are compiling against (maybe some generated classes? in which case rebuilding fixing the problem would make sense.)

Comment: I'm facing a similar problem. Were you able to resolve it?

Comment: Sadly I had to revert the code to non-lambda-exp. For apps which run on production it looks too unreliable to me. Maybe in the future.